# How to play WAV file from Properties.Resources using C#

Tags: c#, wav

How can I play a wav file from `Properties.Resources`?

I try some code, but every time my `Priperties.Resource.myFile` put me `byte[]` but my code need `string` path, not `byte[]` array.

```
    System.Media.SoundPlayer player = new System.Media.SoundPlayer();

    player.SoundLocation = @"myFile.wav";
    player.Play();
```

I don't want to use some temp file. It is possible play direct from Resource?

Thanks for your advice!

Comment: SoundPlayer can only play wav files

Comment: So, Can I play WAV file from Resource?

Comment: If this is what you want. Please change your question to mention WAV file instead of MP3, so that it would not be confusing for other people.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> So, Can I play WAV file from Resource?

You can use the `Stream` property like this:

```
System.Media.SoundPlayer player = new System.Media.SoundPlayer();

player.Stream = new MemoryStream(data);
player.Play();
```

Where `data` is the `byte[]` that you got from the resource file.

**UPDATE:**

`Properties.Resources.myFile` should actually be a stream, so use it directly like this:

```
System.Media.SoundPlayer player = new System.Media.SoundPlayer();

player.Stream = Properties.Resources.myFile;
player.Play();
```

Comment: I try your code, but on `new MemoryStream(data);` I get a error `cannot convert from 'System.IO.UnmanagedMemoryStream' to 'int'`.

Comment: Where `data` is `Properties.Resources.myFile`. File myFile is wav.

Comment: Thank you for your help. Works perfectly.

Answer (score 2):

Two ways can do so as far as I know, see below:

1. **Use file path** 
   First put the file in the root folder of the project, then no matter you run the program under `Debug` or `Release` mode, the file can both be accessed for sure.

   ```
       var basePath = System.AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory;
       SoundPlayer player = new SoundPlayer();
       player.SoundLocation = Path.Combine(basePath, @"./../../Reminder.wav");
       player.Load();
       player.Play();
   ```
2. **Use resource** 
   Follow below animate, add "Exsiting file" to the project.

[image]

```
        SoundPlayer player = new SoundPlayer(Properties.Resources.Reminder);
        player.Play();
```

The strength of this way is:
Only the folder "Release" under the "bin" directory need to be copy when run the program.

Answer (score 0):

For me (VS 2022, .net 6, C # 10) it worked:

1. Import the "myFile.wav" file into the main directory.
2. Change in: Properties (myFile.wav) - Copy to Output Directory to: Copy always.
   Later it was enough to:

   ```
    System.Media.SoundPlayer player = new System.Media.SoundPlayer("myFile.wav");
    player.Load ();
    player.Play ();
   ```